# Ajax in Codeigniter Issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to refresh / reload the page using ajax.

**View:**

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Insert | SP</title>
      <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>bootstrap/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

**Script section**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            function loadNowPlaying(){
      $(this).load('<?php echo base_url().'Store/student' ;?>');
    }
    setInterval(function(){loadNowPlaying()}, 5000);
        });


        </script>
```

**Renaming Code**

```
 </head>
    <body>
        <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>Store/add" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
            <input type="text" name="mail" id="mail"><br>
            <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Insert">
        </form>


        <table id="studata">
           <?php foreach ($students as $student):?>
            <tr>
               <th>Name</th>
               <th>Email</th>
               <th>Password</th>
            </tr>
               <tr>
                <td><?php echo $student->Name;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $student->Email;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $student->Password;?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**My Controller code:**

```
public function student()
    {
        $data["students"] = $this->sp->getstudent();
        $this->load->view('student',$data);
    }
```

**My Model:**

```
 public function getstudent()
    {
         $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('ex_sp');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

The code is working fine but it is loading my whole page [view] and i want to only load the table or some specific container but using the same view. I check a lot of question but did not find what i want, Please check the question instead of down voting.
What is wrong in it? can someone please look at it.

Comment: I'm not seeing any ajax in there.

Comment: You are trying to load the view from jQuery load function into the view itself ?

Comment: Where is your ajax code?

Comment: Upload your ajax code

Comment: check the script section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a **isAjax flag** in your controller and view:

In controller:

```
public function student()
{
        $data["isAjax"] = $_REQUEST['isAjax']; //change it to CI Get/Post method you are using.
        $data["students"] = $this->sp->getstudent();
        $this->load->view('student',$data); //you are sending $data["isAjax"] to view file
}
```

Now you have to check in view if isAjax flag is set then load only table else load entire page:

In View:

```
if($isAjax == 1)
   // Load data only needed for ajax request 
else
   // Load all other data
```

Please note: You will need to send extra param with ajax request as isAjax=1 :

Ajax code Example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "view_file_ajax_call_url",
    method: "POST",
    data: { 'isAjax':1, 'example_data': value},
    }).done(function(data) {
         //operation
    }
```

Comment: In view send extra param with ajax request as isAjax=1 and get it in controller. So if it is ajax request you will have isAjax=1 in view. You have a if condition in view that if(isAjax==1) "load only table" else "load everything"

Comment: still not getting it, can you please add you code example in my code provided above so i can test it.

Comment: @msz Edited the code and provided example. Hope its clear now

Answer (score 0):

In your script section try to change `''` to `""`

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            function loadNowPlaying(){
      $(this).load("<?php echo base_url().'Store/student' ;?>");
    }
    setInterval(function(){loadNowPlaying()}, 5000);
        });


        </script>
```